# Optimizing Method for Function's Parameter

Tags: optimization, numerical-optimization

I have a set of measurements $M$ for a physical value $S$, that depends on 4 parameters ($a_1$, $a_2$, $b$ and $c$). There exists an approximation formula for S, but only considers 3 parameters ($a$, $b$ and $c$). Nevertheless, it is possible to get good results by considering the mean value of $a_1$ and $a_2$ and replace $a = \frac{a_1+a_2}{2}$.

I would like to explore if there is an even better mean value, utilizing the generalized mean $(\frac{1}{2} (a_1^p+a_2^p))^\frac{1}{p}$. In other words, I would like to optimize $p$ so that the sum of the squared errors (SSE) between measurements of S and their estimations from the formula is minimized.

Does anyone has a preferred tool for this job?

Comment: You can use any programming language. You should define a functional describing the error in S (given as a sum of quadrates) written with respect to parameter $p$ and then minimize it with respect to $p$, for example by means of the Newton's method. Can you share your formula for S and your data $a_{1,i}, a_{2,i}, b_{i}, c_{i},~i=1,\dots,n$?